# My Apps,js File (React) is unfortunately not displayed in the Localhost 3000. i get somehow no further i have already tried everything

Tags: reactjs

My Apps.js File (React) is unfortunately not displayed in the Localhost 3000. I get somehow no further I have already tried everything

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    import { About, Footer, Header, Skills, Testimonial, Work } from './container';
    import { Navbar } from './components';
    import './App.scss';
    
    const App = () => (
      <div className="app">
        <Navbar />
        <Header />
        <About />
        <Work />
        <Skills />
        <Testimonial />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: And this is my index.js file                                                                                                
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

Comment: Did you check console both in your editor and browser?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: There is no error displayed, when I want to display the page on localhost the page is completely white and nothing is displayed